# Adding quartzcore to Xcode 4 for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks, quartz-core

I have troubles installing quartzcore on Xcode 4 regarding an iOS application. I just can't find the answer: how to do it? Because when I try to add Quartzcore to the targets of the project, it seems I can only add a Mac OS X framework. All you can do about an iOS framework is creating one.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Xcode 4, in the left sidebar, select the project file at the top:

1) Make sure your target is selected in the main view, and you should see 5 tabs at the top,

2) Click the "Build Phases" tab,

3) Click the arrow to the left of the "Link Binary With Libraries" row,

4) Click the plus button that just appeared at the bottom of that row,

5) Type "QuartzCore" into the search field,

6) You should see a folder named "iOS 4.3" with the "QuartzCore.framework" inside of it,

7) Double click the "QuartzCore.framework" to add it to your current project.

Then it should appear in left sidebar, and you can drag it into the frameworks folder if you wish.

Make sure you do a

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

in any source files that you use the framework.

If you don't see the framework when you search for it, it means you don't have the SDK installed correctly. You probably want to reinstall Xcode at that point.

Comment: The framework appears in the Project Navigator at the project root. If you drag it to the 'Frameworks' group, the link get's broken and the just dragged framework appears in red (missing) on the 'Link with Libraries' build phase tab. To fix this, select the dragged framework on the Project Navigator, and in the right tab uncheck, then re-check the framework file's target membership (checkbox with target name written on it)

Answer (score -5):

I was also experiencing the same problem and I figured that out *without reinstalling the xcode* and *sdk*

### Steps:

- *Download* and *unzip* the compressed *QuartzCore.framework* from [here](http://goo.gl/drrBkI)
- *Open* your project *click* on any of the available *framework*  and choose *show in finder*
- *Paste* the QuartzCore.framework found in the unzipped file there.
- *Click* the project and then *target* and then *link libraries and framework* from *build* phases
- *Click plus* and then type the *Quartz* in the upcoming pop up

There you go.That's it.

**References:**

- [Ref1](http://goo.gl/rB9fMI)
- [Ref2](http://goo.gl/qcItDd)

Comment: @JoshuaJ.McKinnon - I would like you to review your stand on this downvote.This is a working solution.If you think the answer needs improvement you are welcome to edit my answer so that answer lookers will be benifited.

Comment: I don't think there is a constructive way to edit an answer that begins "download an included iOS framework from this google doc". That's not a working solution - it's a dangerous, unreliable hack.