# Objective-C – Undefined symbols

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use a gradient in cocoa touch. I'm using the following code for this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = mainView.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
[mainView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

But I get the following error when I try to compile:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAGradientLayer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in OfficeViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found
>   for architecture i386 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I've tried to do a clean to no avail. Not really sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Make sure you actually included the QuartzCore framework in your project. It should be in the Link Binary With Libraries phases:

[image]

Comment: And the steps to reach that screen are spelled out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6961788/338265

Comment: Another gotcha is when you do this, Xcode might add the framework, but for the wrong Target. Make sure the framework is selected for the Target you're building

Answer (score 3):

Have you included the QuartzCore framework to the project as well? Just adding the headers is not enough.

Comment: Thanks. But why is it that I can use some of the QuartzCore functions (without adding the QuartzCore framework) like the layer property?