# Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am integrating CHartBoost, and while integrating i am getting few issue.
I have attached a screenshot.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
Is it something, with missing libraries?

[image]

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add QuartzCore to your target's linked libraries, [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961788/1218876).