# Using Library at Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I had download Xenofex-MultiColumnTableViewForiOS-0b3fa88 library and plan to use it in my iOS project.

May i know what is step to import and link this library to my project? Just drag and drop the unzipped folder to my project?

I had drag the needed file to my project and try to run it.

The compiler prompt me error below
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EWHeaderHighlightLayer in EWHeaderHighlightLayer.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_EWHeaderHighlightLayer in EWHeaderHighlightLayer.o
      objc-class-ref in EWMultiColumnTableView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransaction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EWMultiColumnTableView.o
  "_kCATransactionDisableActions", referenced from:
      -[EWMultiColumnTableView highlightColumn:] in EWMultiColumnTableView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone advice on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By the look of the linker errors, you need to add the QuartzCore framework to your project. This is where the CALayer class is implemented, along with a load of other things.

There are instructions on how to do this in the top-rated answer to this SO question: [Adding quartzcore to xcode 4 for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956432/adding-quartzcore-to-xcode-4-for-ios).