# Error on first CAAnimation Program

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caanimation

This is what is being called:

```
-(IBAction)preform:(id)sender{
 CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
 [layer setPosition:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
 [layer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 60.0)];
 [layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
 [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

 CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
 [animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)]];
 animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 250.0)];
 [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

This is the error:
I know very little about IOS animations and don't know how to go about this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMu0F.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add framework QuartzCore to your project..

here is how.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961788/1518182