# QuartzCore/CATransform3D.h file not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, quartz-core

I've been getting some strange errors in `XCode 4.6.1`.

When I try to run application on my *iPad* (Version 6.1.3), it gave me error. but when i use *iPhone 6.1 simulator* it work!!

The error point to `UICollectionViewLayout.h`. I don't know where this file came from? I don't even create file in my project with this name (*UICollectionViewLayout*)

see the picture in the link below
[error](http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/12705047/img/Anonymous/Screen-Shot-2013-04-16-at-12.57.00-PM.png)

When I go to Build phases and try to add the framework (`QuartzCore/CATransform3D`), I can't find it!!!

I don't what these problem come from,, I will become crazy soon :(
Someone Help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Quartz library to your project

[Adding quartzcore to xcode 4 for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956432/adding-quartzcore-to-xcode-4-for-ios)

Instead coregraphics.h include this line in your code to use QuartzCore

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: it is there [link](http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/12705212/img/Anonymous/Screen-Shot-2013-04-16-at-1.53.33-PM.png)

Comment: I modified the code based on your comments, see what i got. [error](http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/12705261/img/Anonymous/Screen-Shot-2013-04-16-at-2.04.14-PM.png) the framework is exist!! why xcode can't see it??

Comment: I figure out the problem. it is bug in xcode version. I install the new version xcode 4.6.2. Now, I can add the framework..

Comment: you see what you want to get I suppose