# How to give Top left and top right border of UITextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to give Top left and top right border of UITextfield in my IOS app like as below image. 
[image] 
I'know we can apply background image but i need to do it with coding.

Please help me.

Thanks!
Shailesh

Comment: you mean you wanna add backgroud image programmatically ?

Comment: This looks like a table view cell with an image view and a textfield.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. No i don't want to add image but i want to give top left and top right round border. I don't want to give border in bottom left and bottom right.

Answer (score 5):

To add border color

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

Adding border only for particular area:

```
CALayer *leftBorder = [CALayer layer];
leftBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
leftBorder.borderWidth = 3;
leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height+2);
[textField.layer addSublayer:leftBorder];
```

try above code. change CGRect values. I think this is what exactly you want. [image]

Comment: I want to give round border of top left and top right. I don't want to give round border to bottom left and bottom right. Thanks

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. My requirement is that i want to give border color to botom part of UITextfield and want to give rounded corner border to top left and top right side.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for reply. but when i run your code then i got error :: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in textboxViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: import QuartzCore framework

Comment: Hi, I've added "#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>
" but still i am getting error.

Comment: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> and have to added  QuartzCore framework into your project

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your kind reply. I've added #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>  but still i am getting errors.

Comment: have to added QuartzCore.framework into your project. from framework dropdown list. please check it. refer this[http://stackoverflow.com/a/6961788/966351](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6961788/966351)

Comment: Hi Ashini, Thank you very much for your reply. I've added QuartzCore.framework into my project and it run smoothly but border is not showing in my textbox. Thanks!

Comment: above code works perfectly for me. use my recently added code.

Comment: Hi Ashini, Thank you very much for your reply. I've added your latest code but still it is not showing red border. Thanks!

Comment: shall you please share your code to this mail id ashinipriya@gmail.com i will check it and let you know.. because that code works perfectly for i din't get any issue...

Comment: see my edit.. i have added textfield with red border image...

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for sharing email. I've sent you code and also screenshot of textbox. You see in email textbox top left and top right border are rounded and bottom left and bottom right borders are not rounded corner but there is gray border at bottom of email textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by

```
#Import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

in either viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad method

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to give only border color to bottom because i don't want to give border to top , left and right sides.

Comment: you cant put color only on bottom with any default way. you can use a UIImageView with desired color behind UItextfield for this

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thank you for your reply. is it not possible in IOS UITextfield to set border bottom color like as web? Thanks

Comment: nope there are alot of limitations in mobile application development as compared to Web development but it is way better and fun to do mobile app development specially iOS development. 

if you liked my answer to your problem, plz accept it :) thnx